# Can the unbounded knapsack problem be described as a matrix exponentiation?

Tags: dynamic-programming, linear-algebra, knapsack-problems

It seems that the general approach to a dynamic programming problem is to formulate a recurrence relation and then either implement a top down recursive solution or a bottom up iterative solution.

But if there's a recurrence relation I think that means we could potentially represent the problem as a state vector and a matrix updates the state through a multiplication. This approach can be used to generate the [Fibonacci sequence](http://www.usrsb.in/blog/blog/2011/04/10/using-matrices-to-generate-the-fibonacci-sequence/) for example.

Can this linear algebra approach be applied generally to any dynamic programming problem such as the [unbounded knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem?

Answer (score 2):

For the Fibonacci sequence, the recurrence relation is *linear*.  That's why it can be represented as a matrix representation, i.e., using linear algebra.  If the recurrence relation isn't linear, you can't do something like that.

So, no, you can't always do that.